# invalid expression flag inside a jquery .ajax() callback function

Tags: jquery

I'm getting an invalid expression flag error which I don't know what that means.

```
jQueryAjaxCall(endpointUrl, methodToCall, dictQueryStringPairs, contentTypeOverride, returnDataType, function (httpResponse)
{
    if (showalerts)
        alert("Calling BindDroopdown from Models.  model list recieved back based on modelTypeName: " + modelTypeName+ "and missid: " + missid+ ".  Count results from ObjectCount(dictModels): " + ObjectCount(dictModels));

    ...rest of code
});
```

showAlerts is a global variable defined at the top of my page.  I use it as a flag to turn on and off some testing I was doing today with the alerts.

Note ObjectCount is just a helper I created:

```
function ObjectCount(object) 
{
    var count = 0;

    if (object === null)
        return 0;

    for (key in object)
    {
        count = count + 1;
    }

    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace ObjectCount(dictmodel) with dictmodel.length